# Connect 2 hard drives of different manufacturers

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Seagate 40G IDE PATA hard disk, 1.5G RAM and I would like to extend my computer with another 40G hard-disk manufactured by Maxtor. I have Ubuntu 10.10 and Windows XP on different partitions.

Will it be OK if I extend hard disks by different manufacturers? Is there any risk of disk failure in the future?

Comment: Yes, it's ok. The risk of disk failure is the same per disk.

Comment: I'm not too sure if you actually understand that you can't connect two disks to *extend each other*. You'll have two independent disks in your PC, with 40G each. That's all.

Comment: I've got the same issue.  I even have them in the same RAID array (gasp!!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hang the second one in. But you need to make sure that you jumper the Master Disk appropriate(If you have to set this).

There is no implication on having two disks in your case.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you are always going to have risk with two obviously-old disks. There is also a mathematical increase in failure when you go from one to two disks, and when you say "would like to extend another 40G", I think spanning disks. If you mean combining them into one partition, I really would not do that due to the age of the disks since if on fails, you are suddenly in a situation where data recovery requires better tools since all the data is not just on one drive. It could be harder for you to recover.

Normally I would not think twice about having two disks, but yours are old, so be careful how you do it, and make sure you have any critical data backed up.